# Prove three bisectors always meet at a common point in any triangle

Tags: geometry

How do you prove that three bisectors meet at a common point in any triangle? I have read carefully the content in Kiselev but cannot devise a proof on my own.

Is the proof for this complicated?

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the title.

Comment: Angle bisectors (incenter) or side bisectors (circumcenter)?

Comment: Bisectors in a triangle. Angle

Comment: Trig Ceva makes it obvious.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio, could you be more explicit about that proof. The proof that is based on "trig Ceva"?

Answer (score 0):

Let the vertices of the triangle be $P_1, P_2, P_3$.

Let $B_1$ be the bisector of the angle $P_3 P_1 P_2$.

Let $B_2$ be the bisector of the angle $P_1 P_2 P_3$.

Let $B_3$ be the bisector of the angle $P_2 P_3 P_1$.

The key observation is

> A point $Q$ is on $B_1$ iff the distance of $Q$ to the side $P_1 P_2$ is the same as the distance of $Q$ to the side $P_1 P_3$.

Analogous statements hold for $B_2$ and $B_3$.

Let $O$ be the intersection of $B_1$ and $B_2$. Then the distances of $O$ to all three sides are the same. Therefore, $O$ is also on $B_3$ and so the three bisectors meet at $O$.